How to hide border on select box when item is selected
I am trying to remove the border that appears around the selected item in a select list. I can remove the border around the select element itself, but when I select an item the item has a border around it.



 .selectbox {
      min-height: 30 px;
      max-height: 30 px;
      border: 0;
      border-color: "white";
      font-size: 16px;
      outline: "none";
    }
 <div class="css-view-175oi2r" style="width: 400px; background-color: rgb(0, 128, 0); padding: 10px;">
      <div class="css-view-175oi2r" style="box-shadow: none; border-radius: 50px; display: flex; flex: 1 1 0%; place-content: center; min-height: 40px; max-height: 40px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
        <select class="selectbox">
          <option value="car" label="Car">Car</option>
          <option value="rv" label="RV">RV</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

   



https://jsfiddle.net/nxc2or0d/12/

You almost had it. Just remove the quotes from outline: "none";

You don't need to add quotes to values as long as they are not string literals like url, text content, grid areas etc. So also remove quotes from <color> value "white".

Thank you for the responses. outline was the issue here., Although my code originally was derived from my React Expo project and in React Native you need to use outlineStyle : none instead when creating your stylesheet.

You do not need to add any single quote(' ') or double quote(" ") around the CSS property value. You just need to add plain value as you have added for the font-size, and height.
Example:
.selectbox {
  min-height: 30 px;
  max-height: 30 px;
  border: 0;
  border-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  background: white;
}



.container {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 128, 0);
  padding: 10px;
}

.select-container {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 0%;
  place-content: center;
  min-height: 40px;
  max-height: 40px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.selectbox {
  min-height: 30 px;
  max-height: 30 px;
  border: 0;
  border-color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  background: white;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="select-container">
    <select class="selectbox">
      <option value="car" label="Car">Car</option>
      <option value="rv" label="RV">RV</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>



